# What is the best-looking way to produce enlarged mathematical symbols in equation mode using lmodern?

Tags: equations, symbols, lmodern

I noticed that there is no way to produce a larger version of the summation symbol when writing equations. This

```
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{equation}
\sum
\end{equation}
```

cannot be magnified using any commands. In looking for answers, I read that perhaps this is a bug, and the `lmodern` font does not contain any large versions of mathematical symbols. I am not sure if that is true. I have attempted to use some packages such as `exscale` to change this, but I have not been able to produce enlarged symbols, even if I remove `lmodern`. I do not want to make the entire equation larger -- JUST the summation symbol, for example.

I would like to keep the `lmodern` font, but simply scale up the symbols. Is there a way to do this that looks natural?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Declare a math version. With the legacy toolchain, `\DeclareMathVersion` and then select a larger font. With `unicode-math`, `\setmathfont[version=bigmath, Scale=1.25]{Latin Modern Math}` or whatever settings you prefer. Sorry I don’t have the chance to turn this into a MWE right now.

Comment: I could not use `unicode-math` since I am working with pdflatex.
I have not used 
\DeclareMathVersion
before, but I will see if I can find anything that will work for me.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to increase the size of the symbols separately. DeclareMathVersion does not seem to work with pdflatex. And no solution I have found allows symbols to be enlarged individually -- it's always the entire section that has to be altered.